# Getting a Permissions error while setting up a hangouts chat bot

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm following this guid to setup a hangouts bot, https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-publish

On step 4, when I go to the configuration tab on the API I keep getting this error:

```
The API "chat.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't 
have permission to access it
```

In the permissions section there are 2 accounts. Myself and the service account that I just made. Both are set as owners.

Did I miss a step? The doc I'm following seems to say I should be able to edit the configuration now.

Comment: It seems you cannot use personal gmail accounts to use this API. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74084482

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with multiple accounts. Try using an Incognito window and logging in through there. If this is the problem, you may want to file a bug through the issue tracker.

Comment: As a side note, I get the same error msg from my consumer Gmail account (because Hangouts Chat only works for G Suite [paying] customers at this time), so I had to switch the login to my G Suite company account in order for it to work.